# Is there a way in Perforce we can create views as in cleartool

Tags: perforce, clearcase, cleartool, p4v

General question: Can we create views in perforce likewise we do in cleartool? I know we can create a `workspace` in perforce.

Comment: Now that your original question was asked and answered ("Can we create views in Perforce like Clearcase views?"), you should put your second question as a separate post rather than editing this question to add additional questions.

Comment: @Mark: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560040/can-we-create-labels-in-perforce. This is link for second question. Please reply to that

Comment: Sure.  Make sure you mark this question as answered if the answer was satisfactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know ClearCase, but from what I've read, it appears that views in ClearCase are analogous to Perforce workspaces.  For details on Perforce workspaces, check the configuration details in the [manual](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.configuration.html#d0e401).

Comment: This is correct.  A p4 workspace is the same (with minor variances) as a CC view.

Comment: In clearcase, views are only shortcuts. It takes a very less space as these are just shortcuts. But in perforce, workspace is a having complete files